# exclude azure data factory connections and integration runtime from azure devops sync

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So we have configured ADF to use GIT under DevOps.
Problem is our connection details are getting synced between dev\qa\master branches which are causing issues as each environment has its own SQL Servers.
Is there any way to keep connections and IR out of sync operation between branches?

Comment: Had you solved this problem? I'm facing the same issue and not finding anything clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Connections rather have to be parameterized than removed from a deployment pipeline.

Parameterization can be done by using "pipeline" and "variable groups" **variables**

As an example, a pipeline variable `adf-keyvault` can be used to point to a rigt KeyVault instance  that belongs to a certain environment:

```
adf-keyvault = "adf-kv-yourProjectName-$(Environment)"
```

Variable `$Environment` is declared on a variable groups level, so each environment has own value mapped, for instance:

```
$Environment = 'dev' #development
$Environment = 'stg' #staging
$Environment = 'prd' #production
```

Therefore the final value of `adf-keyvault`, depending on environment, resolves into:

```
adf-keyvault = "adf-kv-yourProjectName-dev" 
adf-keyvault = "adf-kv-yourProjectName-stg" 
adf-keyvault = "adf-kv-yourProjectName-prd"
```

And each Key Vault stores connection string to a database server in secret with the same name across environments. For instance:

```
adf-sqldb-connectionstring = Server=123.123.123.123;Database=adf-sqldb-dev;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Because an initial setup of CI/CD pipelines in Azure Data Factory can be complex in a first glance, I blogged recently a step-by-step guide about this topic: [Azure Data Factory & DevOps – Setting-up Continuous Delivery Pipeline](https://www.alexvolok.com/2020/adf-devops-setting-up-ci-cd/)

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59503805/8446413) Which also asks how to use parameters for SQL connection information in ADF.

Your solution should also leverage Managed Identities for creating the access policies in the Key Vault this can be done via ARM.

One additional comment would be that the Linked Services would be where the parameter substitutions of these values would occur.